# Sorting the results of php for each loop into desending order (highest score top)

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to display the results of a php for each loop in decending order, from reading a few similar questions here I have worked out I need to put the results of of the loop into an array then sort that, I have attempted to do that with the following code and getting a black page for the result..

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `live`");
    /*every time it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
    while($liveuserscores[]=mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    //Delete first line
    array_pop($liveuserscores); 
    //echo '<hr><pre>'; print_r($liveuserscores); echo '</pre><hr>';
    $sortedarr = [];
    foreach ($liveuserscores as $user) {
$userpoints = $user['name'].": ".number_format($user['q1points']+$user['q2points']+$user['q3points']+$user['q4points']+$user['q5points']+$user['q6points']+$user['q7points']+$user['q8points']+$user['q9points']+$user['q10points']+$user['q11points']+$user['q12points']+$user['q13points']+$user['q14points']+$user['q15points']+$user['q16points']+$user['q17points']+$user['q18points']+$user['q19points']+$user['q20points']+$user['q21points']+$user['q22points']+$user['q23points']+$user['q24points']+$user['q25points']+$user['q26points']+$user['q27points']+$user['q28points']+$user['q29points']+$user['q30points']+$user['q31points']+$user['q32points']+$user['q33points']+$user['q34points']+$user['q35points']+$user['q36points']+$user['q37points']+$user['q38points']+$user['q39points']+$user['q40points'])."<br>";
$sortedarr = [] = $userpoints;
}
sort($sortedarr);
echo '<hr><pre>'; print_r($sortedarr); echo '</pre><hr>';
```

I also have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

in the code but getting no error messages.

a sample of `print_r($liveuserscores);` (with pre tags) is..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 56
            [name] => Glen
            [datetime] => Tuesday 02nd Nov 21 21:26pm
            [q1seen] => YES
            [q1pickedans] => 2
            [q1timetoans] => 2.375 
            [q1points] => 8
            [q2seen] => YES
            [q2pickedans] => 3
            [q2timetoans] => 3.363
            [q2points] => 7
        )
)
```

I can get just the sum of users scores to display with this code...

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `live` ORDER BY name DESC");
    /*every time it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
    while($liveuserscores[]=mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    //Delete first line
    array_pop($liveuserscores); 
    //echo '<hr><pre>'; print_r($liveuserscores); echo '</pre><hr>';
    foreach ($liveuserscores as $user) {
echo $user['name'].": ".number_format($user['q1points']+$user['q2points']+$user['q3points']+$user['q4points']+$user['q5points']+$user['q6points']+$user['q7points']+$user['q8points']+$user['q9points']+$user['q10points']+$user['q11points']+$user['q12points']+$user['q13points']+$user['q14points']+$user['q15points']+$user['q16points']+$user['q17points']+$user['q18points']+$user['q19points']+$user['q20points']+$user['q21points']+$user['q22points']+$user['q23points']+$user['q24points']+$user['q25points']+$user['q26points']+$user['q27points']+$user['q28points']+$user['q29points']+$user['q30points']+$user['q31points']+$user['q32points']+$user['q33points']+$user['q34points']+$user['q35points']+$user['q36points']+$user['q37points']+$user['q38points']+$user['q39points']+$user['q40points'])."<br>"; 
}
```

But the order is not sorted by largest score at the top.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, what's the use of a `while` loop without any body?

Comment: why dont you just put  `desc` or `asc` on `query db` ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM live ORDER BY name DESC`

Comment: I've tried to show errors to help me resolve the problem so I can see what is going wrong but get none, the while loop = every time it fetches the row, adds it to array and The db query fetches everything I want to sort on the result of the sum of all q points. These are called [q1points], [q2points] etc (up to [q40points] in the db and the sum is per row (name)

Comment: I can't use ORDER BY xyz DESC because the order i want them in is a sum of several xyz's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few problem with this code
first
`array_pop($liveuserscores);` 
is removing the item you have just fetched from your array so you always working with a empty array, also array_pop remove the last element and not the first.
Also I-m pretty sure that this `$sortedarr = [] = $userpoints;` will reset $sortedarr to an empty array

Also sort function doesn't know how to sort an associative array, you have to define a sorting function using usort.

If I understood your question correctly you want to sort the results by the score.
And the score is the sum of few different column
You can change the query like this:

```
SELECT *,
 q1points + q2points + ... + q40points AS score
FROM live
ORDER BY score DESC
```

So now you don't have to sort it manually

you can do

```
$sortedarr = mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo '<hr><pre>'; print_r($sortedarr); echo '</pre><hr>';
```